# afterSetExtremes callback for highcharts

Tags: highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm creating a highchart using the lazy_highcharts gem. I'd like to make use of the afterSetExtremes callback to regenerate some other data on the page on zooming. I've tried several ways, currently trying:

```
 @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
                    f.chart(:zoomType =>'x', :defaultSeriesType => 'spline')
                    f.x_axis(:type=> 'datetime', :events => {:afterSetExtremes => "functon(event){alert('something')}"} )
end
```

But that gives me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object functon(event){alert('something')} has no method 'apply'
```

in the javascript console when I zoom the chart. I assume this has something to do with the generator not correctly setting up the callback function, setting it as a string instead of interpreting it as a function.

I've also tried to set it on my chart object via javascript after creation, but so far have had no luck with that. A few attempts below

```
chart_my_id4.xAxis.events = {setExtremes: function(event) {
      alert('set extremes');
    }};
chart_my_id4.xAxis[1].events = {setExtremes: function(event) {
      alert('set extremes');
    }};
```

No luck there either.

Any insight appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not too familiar with ... ruby, but I took a look at the source on github and they do the following when they set functions into attributes:

```
:formatter => "function() { return this.x; }".js_code
```

It would be worth a try to add that .js_code and see if it works so you end up with:

```
 @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
   f.chart(:zoomType =>'x', :defaultSeriesType => 'spline')
   f.x_axis(:type=> 'datetime', :events => {
     :afterSetExtremes => "functon(event){alert('something')}".js_code
   })
end
```

Comment: I'll try that. After messing with this for a while I abandoned it and went straight to the JS, got everything working. but I will try to circle back and verify this. Would be nice if it was as simple as that to make work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that gem, but in standard Highcharts 3.0 you can add event in that way:

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(){
            alert('x');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like lazy highcharts is currently based on versions v2.3.3, and that doesn't work for me (no method 'update'). Will see about getting the newest version. May have to abandon the gem and go with the JS directly but man it made things easy to stay in Ruby.

Comment: Since doc for that gem is really limited (in the fact, doesn't exists), could you show example how do you add formatter for tooltip or datalabels? What can I say for sure is that returned is `object`(hash), instead of `function`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that :

```
 LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
   ...
   f.xAxis(:events => { :afterSetExtremes => after_set_extremes_function})
 end
```

-

```
 def after_set_extremes_function
   %|function(e) {
     chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
     chart.showLoading('Loading data...');
     $.getJSON("/path_to_your_action?start="+Math.round(e.min)+"&end="+Math.round(e.max), function(data) {
          chart.series[0].setData(data);
          chart.hideLoading();
        }
      }
    );
   }|.js_code
 end
```