# rCharts - highcharts speed

Tags: highcharts, rcharts

General question on the speed of (rCharts) highcharts rendering.

Given the following code

```
rm(list = ls())
require(rCharts)

set.seed(2)
time_stamp<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-05-20 01:00",tz=""),to=as.POSIXct("2014-05-22 20:00",tz=""),by="1 min")
Data1<-abs(rnorm(length(time_stamp))*50)
Data2<-rnorm(length(time_stamp))
time<-as.numeric(time_stamp)*1000

CombData=data.frame(time,Data1,Data2)
CombData$Data1=round(CombData$Data1,2);CombData$Data2=round(CombData$Data2,2);
HCGraph <- Highcharts$new()

HCGraph$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'Data1')),
                   list(title = list(text = 'Data2'),
                        opposite =TRUE)))

HCGraph$series(data = toJSONArray2(CombData[,c('time','Data1')], json = F, names = F),enableMouseTracking=FALSE,shadow=FALSE,name = "Data1",type = "line")
HCGraph$series(data = toJSONArray2(CombData[,c('time','Data2')], json = F, names = F),enableMouseTracking=FALSE,shadow=FALSE,name = "Data2",type = "line",yAxis=1)
HCGraph$xAxis(type = "datetime"); HCGraph$chart(zoomType = "x")
HCGraph$plotOptions(column=list(animation=FALSE),shadow=FALSE,line=list(marker=list(enabled=FALSE)));
HCGraph
```

Produces a highcharts graph of 2 series each 4021 points in length and renders immediately.

However, if I increase the timespan to say 10 days (8341 points) the resulting plot can take several  minutes to generate.

I'm aware there are several modifications that can be made to highcharts for better performance,
[Highcharts Performance Enhancement Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768021/highcharts-performance-enhancement-method),
however, are there any changes I can make from an R / rCharts perspective to speed up performance?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to disable markers / shadows / animations? How about scenario when you dont use rChart, but native highcharts ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebastian. Yes, I had previously tried these parameters, the code has been updated, however, they do not yield significant improvements in rendering speed. My preference for using rcharts is to avoid diving too deeply into highcharts js and thus I was hoping something could be optimized within R itself.

Comment: After some further research I think the best approach is to try and make use of the 'lazy loading' feature. Specifically, hook into afterSetExtremes event as defined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554153/aftersetextremes-callback-for-highcharts. Hopefully, this will be possible to do directly with R as discussed here: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/11